# wpf custom textbox with a depedency property crash

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Here's my first attempt at using extending a textbox with a dependency property, based on an example I found online.

My solution consists of 2 projects: A wpf application, and a class library.

Here's my class library:

```
namespace CustomTextBox
{
public class CustTextBox : TextBox
{
  public string SecurityId
  {
     get { return (string)GetValue(SecurityIdProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SecurityIdProperty, value); }
  }

  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SecurityIdProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(CustTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));
 }
}
```

Here's the wpf application xaml where I attempt to use the CustTextBox (the application itself is nothing special, just using caliburn.micro.start)

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApplication.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:CustomTextBox;assembly=CustomTextBox">

<Grid>
    <custom:CustTextBox Text="TESTING"></custom:CustTextBox>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Running it results in a crash on this line:

```
<custom:CustTextBox Text="TESTING"></custom:CustTextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SecurityIdProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(CustTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

To:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SecurityIdProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("SecurityId", typeof(string), typeof(CustTextBox), new PropertyMetadata("0"));
```

Actually you should be able to use `nameof(SecurityId)` to avoid any magic strings.

**EDIT:** I also noticed how you are passing `0` to the `PropertyMetadata`.  This is not the same type as you have declared the property.  You have declared it as a `string` but are passing an `int`.  Either pass this as `PropertyMetadata("0")` or change the property type to be an `int`.

Comment: I made the change, but I still have the same problem. Regarding your last comment: what is a magic string and are you suggesting that "SecurityId" be replaced with nameof(SecurityId)?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm suggesting because if you renamed the `SecurityId` property but forgot to change the `"SecurityId"` in the dependency property you would have issues and a hard time finding out why.

Comment: Ok, but even with nameof(SecurityId) as the first argument to Register, the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks. I used the propdp TAB TAB shortcut and didn't know I had to change that last argument.

Comment: Glad you got sorted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151641/discussion-between-jana-andropov-and-stephen-wilson).